# merge sound file audio and record in Widows 8 Metro Windows Store application

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8

I have two sound files that I need to merge. One is an audio file and the other is a recording file.

I am using c# to build a Metro Style App. Is there any libraries or any functionality in .net I can use to complete this?

Comment: This is difficult to do in C++ let alone a restriction platform.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/), I don't know if they have a version for Windows store apps.

An option could be to write .net web service that uses NAudio to do the job of merging the audio files and send it back to your app.